# How to obtain library information using Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

Using Android NDK is it possible (from native C-code) to get a list of loaded .so libraries? I am looking for an Android-version of the iOS functions _dyld_image_count()/_dyld_get_image_name().

Also is it possible to get the library name of the .so containing a specific function (on iOS this function is dladdr()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read and parse `/proc/self/maps` file. It contains which address each shared object loaded for your application. `self` will help your application to read its own info.

[nm](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) command line utiliy which is also available in Android NDK can show you which symbols are available from certain shared object files. You can look how it is implemented and try to utilize the same libraries, but it won't be trivial.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for regarding a similar mechanism to iOS _dyld_image_count()/_dyld_get_image_name(). Thanks! And for the dladdr-function it seems it is partly supported by the NDK.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can Get this Here is Sample

```
try {

 Set<String> libs = new HashSet<String>();

 String mapsFile = "/proc/" + android.os.Process.myPid() + "/maps";

  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 

FileReader(mapsFile));

        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            if (line.endsWith(".so")) {

                int n = line.lastIndexOf(" ");

                libs.add(line.substring(n + 1));

            }

        }

        Log.d("Ldd", libs.size() + " libraries:");

        for (String lib : libs) {

            Log.d("Ldd", lib);

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        // Do some error handling...

    } catch (IOException e) {

        // Do some error handling...

    }
```

try this This Might Help You

Comment: Thanks, but what I am looking for is a way to list (not load) the .so libraries that the Android app currently has loaded.